# telnet with pexpect lib in python

Tags: python, telnet, pexpect

i want run telnet in python with pexpect lib and i want if telnet password is true, print true and wrong, print wrong...
now my code is:

```
import pexpect

ip="192.168.1.1"
password="admin"

child = pexpect.spawn("telnet "+ip+" -l admin", timeout=2)
child.expect ("Password:")
child.sendline ("admin")
child.expect(b"> ")
child.sendline ("ls")
child.close()
result = child.signalstatus
if result == 1:
    print ("Success")
else:
    print ("Bad Result")
```

in top code, when password is true, script work good and display "success" but when password is wrong, script not display "bad result" and just display a lot of error..

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

When you entered bad password, you are not handling it gracefully so it raises a timeout exception and the child.close() was never executed. The errors you see are only the exception related print messages.

Solution: 
You can pass a list of expectations and handle them accordingly

```
child = pexpect.spawn("telnet "+ip+" -l admin", timeout=2)
child.expect ("Password:")
child.sendline ("admin")
result = child.expect(["> ", pexpect.TIMEOUT])
if result == 0: #means prompt was caught successfully i.e. password was correct
    child.sendline ("ls")
    print ("Success")
elif result == 1:
    print ("Bad Result")
child.close()
```

In fact, this can be made a function, where you can handle more exceptions and special scenarios as per your use-case.